# What does "::type=0" in first template mean?

Tags: c++, templates

The following is part of the code：

```
// Null-delimited strings, and the like.

template < typename CharT,
           typename std::enable_if <
               std::is_pointer<CharT>::value &&
               !std::is_array<CharT>::value &&
               std::is_integral<typename std::remove_pointer<CharT>::type>::value &&
               sizeof(typename std::remove_pointer<CharT>::type) == 1,
               int >::type = 0 >
contiguous_bytes_input_adapter input_adapter(CharT b)
{
    auto length = std::strlen(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(b));
    const auto* ptr = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(b);
    return input_adapter(ptr, ptr + length);
}

template<typename InputType>
JSON_HEDLEY_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT
static basic_json parse(InputType&& i,
                        const parser_callback_t cb = nullptr,
                        const bool allow_exceptions = true,
                        const bool ignore_comments = false)
{
    basic_json result;
    parser(detail::input_adapter(std::forward<InputType>(i)), cb, allow_exceptions, ignore_comments).parse(true, result);
    return result;
}

static const char *g_sJsonTextInput = "{"
"  \"_nested\": {"
"    \"_bool\": false,"
"    \"_int\": 0,"
"    \"_double\": 0,"
"    \"_string\": \"foo\""
"  }"
"}";

parse(g_sJsonTextInput);
```

I think the result of "std::enable_if<...>::type" is the first template parameter, is that correct?
If it’s right, how to understand "::type = 0"?

Please help, Thanks!

Comment: TL;DR `typename std::enable_if<true, int>::type` boils down to `int`. You then have `template <typename CharT, int=0>`. The `int=0` part is just an anonymous non-type template parameter of type `int` with default argument `0`.

Answer (score 8):

`typename std::enable_if<...>::type` is the type of the second template parameter. That parameter is unnamed. It has a default argument `= 0`, which is used if you don't specify any argument for it (which is the intent here).

> the result of "std::enable_if<...>::type" is the first template parameter

It's either the second parameter of `enable_if` if the condition is true, or an invalid type if the condition is false. It being invalid would trigger SFINAE and disable this function for a specific `CharT` type.

In modern C++, you would use a shorter notation:

- `std::enable_if_t<...>` (without `typename` and `::type`).
- `std::is_..._v<...>` (instead of `std::is_...<...>::value`).

Also, instead of `int` `=0` you should use `std::nullptr_t` `=nullptr`. With an `int`, user can inadvertently create several different instantiations of your template by passing different integers to it, which is impossible with `std::nullptr_t` because it only has one possible value.

Or, if you use C++20, you should use the `requires` notation.

Answer (score 2):

This is SFINAE (substitution failure is not an error) template stuff. If we look at [enable_if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if), then it says:

```
template< bool B, class T = void >
struct enable_if;
```

> If B is true, std::enable_if has a public member typedef type, equal
> to T; otherwise, there is no member typedef.

So if the big boolean expression evaluates to true, the `enable_if` expression substitutes to basically `int = 0` which is ok, but if it evaluates to false it substitutes to  `= 0` which fails to compile - but only results in a compilation error if all other possible substitutions also fail (per the SFINAE name).

Answer (score 1):

`std::enable_if<...>::type` is a hack of the template resolution system.

The SFINAE principle states that if a template resolution is not possible for a function call, the compilation should not fail, but simply try the next (and possibly worse) template resolution.

std::enable_if is defined in such a way that if it's first argument evaluates to false, the ::type is not defined.

to break it down:

```
template <typename Something,
    typename int = 0>
void function() {}
```

is valid C++.

So is `std::enable_if<condition_evaluating_to_true, SomeType>::type` (and the whole expression evaluates to SomeType).

`std::enable_if<condition_evaluating_to_false, SomeType>::type` is not a valid expression.

`std::enable_if<...>::type = 0` roughly means "only apply the  template resolution containing `std::enable_if` when the condition within enable_if evaluates to true".